# dhcp: Host name lookup failure

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, dhcp

I changed configuration of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1` and used `ifdown` and `ifup` to reset it. Then used `ifconfig eth1 dhcp start` it does not work and say:`dhcp: Host name lookup failure`. Are you know what caused it to behave so? 
distro:Fedora 12

Answer (score 3):

That's not the way `ifconfig` works. Your `ifconfig` invocation is understood as ‘configure device `eth1`, setting its address to be that of host `start`’. There's no host named ‘start’, so `ifconfig` fails.

If you configured the device correctly in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1`, all you need to do to run DHCP is to bring it up with `ifup eth1`.